# do I need to declare serialUID in subclasses?

Tags: java

I have a `Serializable` class for which I have explicitly declared `serialUID`.

(I did this to be sure the serialization won't break if I later change this my class).

Now I have the same concern for subclasses of this class.

I can't understand if I should define `serialUID` for them as well (with the same value) or if this `serialUID` from the base class shall be enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `serialUID` applies only to the particular class it's in; in fact, it's usually `private`. To quote the Javadoc for `Serializable`:

> Such declarations apply only to the immediately declaring class--`serialVersionUID` fields are not useful as inherited members.

Comment: Just to add. The general declaration is {ACCESS_MODIFIER} static final long serialVersionUID = 42L; It is static.. so no inheritance. @Chrylis +1 for the answer.

Comment: @ABP a static field would still be a field of a subclass. so probably static is not relevant for the answer above.. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alex - My point is in java you can not override static fields its at class level nothing to do with the Object.

Answer (score 0):

SerialVersionUID is used if you change the implementation of a class, but still want to be able to serialize/deserialise objects saved in the "old" format. So this means that you have to implement it in the subclass as well, if you want to change the subclass but not the superclass. However, if you dont need this "version control" you dont have to use SerialVersionUID at all.

**The serialVersionUID should be specific to every class, but it doesn't have to be (many people 'cheat' and just define it as 1L). Subclasses should get their own serialVersionUID. The serialVersionUID is specific to a class, not an object, since they are static. I don't think it matters if two different classes have the same serialVersionUID, since it is used in deserializing objects of the same class.**

Comment: Incorrect; the docs point out that a generated version is *extremely* unstable across compilers, and it's entirely possible to get false mismatches between identical classes compiled in different circumstances.